# Manga where MC comes back from another world after being trained by the demon lord

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

MC was summoned back to the hero academy for people who came back after they've defeated the demon lord. When he was summoned to another world, it's the world where the demon lord has exterminated all life, and the demon lord trains him to be strong enough to kill her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this ***[A Brave Man Trained by the Worst Demon King, Unrivaled in the School of Returnees From Another World](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ijjdf61/saikyou-no-maou-ni-kitaerareta-yuusha-isekai-kikanshatati-no-gakuen-de-musou-suru)***...?

> Without possessing the unique skill blessed by the goddess, **a boy named Kujou Kyouya failed to save the world. He was ridiculed as a “failed hero” at the interdimensional-level academy where returned heroes who had saved many worlds gathered. However, he became the strongest and most unique hero, having trained for 30,000 years in another world with the most evil demon king, Felice, who has destroyed 3,000 worlds!** Now Kyouya's unique skill is so powerful that he cannot even be defeated by the strongest heroes! The legend of a boy trained by the most evil demon king, begins!

[image]

[image]